# Help figuring out how to write the English description of a turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

So I generally understand how to follow a flow-diagram of a Turing Machine, but I'm going over how to write the "steps" in English and am having a bit of trouble. The problem is as follows: "Give the English description of a Turing machine that decides this language: {$1^{n}$$2^{n}$, $n > 0$}"

I understand that the string is basically: "there must be the same number of 1's and 2's in the string, and there are more than 0 1's and 2's (the string cannot be empty), but how would I write the English steps for this language? Could someone explain the process on how to break it down and write it?

Comment: I don't think "English description" is a formal concept. They just want you to describe how such a TM would work, in words.

Comment: So in essence, whatever the diagram would do, just write that out in words?

Comment: Describe the idea of the TM-algorithm.

Comment: Imagine you had to explain it to your grandfather.